# scatterplot of mean, max and min with datetime

Tags: r, datetime

I am working for the first time with a table containing dates and time and I am really struggling with making what I thought it was a simple plot.
The table looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
    ~A,                   ~B
    , "2018-01-01 18:33:00", "2018-01-06 16:00:00"
    , "2018-01-01 19:37:00", "2018-01-14 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-01 19:52:00", "2018-03-29 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-01 20:23:00", "2018-02-26 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-01 20:47:00", "2018-02-03 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 01:07:00", "2018-01-06 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 03:57:00", "2018-01-05 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 14:10:00", "2018-01-13 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 17:55:00", "2018-01-10 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 18:11:00", "2018-03-04 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 18:22:00", "2018-01-25 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 18:36:00", "2018-01-09 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 18:49:00", "2018-02-04 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 20:08:00", "2018-02-05 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 22:21:00", "2018-01-22 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 22:25:00", "2018-02-04 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-03 02:20:00", "2018-02-25 16:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 09:19:00", "2018-01-09 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 09:51:00", "2018-01-13 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-03 09:55:00", "2018-03-10 13:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 10:07:00", "2018-02-01 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 11:57:00", "2018-04-07 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 12:00:00", "2018-01-26 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 12:09:00", "2018-01-04 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-03 12:31:00", "2018-01-08 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 12:36:00", "2018-02-19 16:00:00"
)
```

There are several points per each day and I would like to make a scatterplot containing just the mean, the max and the min per each day.

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.
Andre

Comment: mean of what? Your data *only* contains datetimes.

Comment: Also: can you please provide a minimal reproducible example, e.g. by posting the output of `dput(yourDataFrame[1:20,])`.

Comment: Every day between B and A there is a difference in time. I would like to calculate the maximum, the minimum and the mean as an average in time per day, and plot them.

Comment: Maybe add that information to your question with example how are you calculating the difference and what plots have you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) # for manipulating data
library(lubridate) # for working with dates

df <- tribble(
    ~A,                   ~B
    , "2018-01-01 18:33:00", "2018-01-06 16:00:00"
    , "2018-01-01 19:37:00", "2018-01-14 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-01 19:52:00", "2018-03-29 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-01 20:23:00", "2018-02-26 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-01 20:47:00", "2018-02-03 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 01:07:00", "2018-01-06 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 03:57:00", "2018-01-05 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 14:10:00", "2018-01-13 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 17:55:00", "2018-01-10 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 18:11:00", "2018-03-04 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 18:22:00", "2018-01-25 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 18:36:00", "2018-01-09 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 18:49:00", "2018-02-04 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 20:08:00", "2018-02-05 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-02 22:21:00", "2018-01-22 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-02 22:25:00", "2018-02-04 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-03 02:20:00", "2018-02-25 16:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 09:19:00", "2018-01-09 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 09:51:00", "2018-01-13 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-03 09:55:00", "2018-03-10 13:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 10:07:00", "2018-02-01 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 11:57:00", "2018-04-07 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 12:00:00", "2018-01-26 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 12:09:00", "2018-01-04 15:30:00"
    , "2018-01-03 12:31:00", "2018-01-08 15:00:00"
    , "2018-01-03 12:36:00", "2018-02-19 16:00:00"
)


df <- df %>% # take the dataframe
    mutate(A = ymd_hms(A) # turn strings into datetimes
           , B = ymd_hms(B)) %>%
    mutate(date_of_A = floor_date(A, unit = "days")) %>% # write the date of A into a new column
    mutate(difference = B - A) %>% # calculate the difference
    group_by(date_of_A) %>% # and now per date...
    summarise(avg_time_difference = mean(difference) # calculate the mean...
              , max_time_difference = max(difference) # the max...
              , min_time_difference = min(difference)) # and the min of the difference

df %>%
    gather("variable", "value", -date_of_A) %>%
    ggplot(aes(date_of_A, value, colour = variable)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: that's very impressive, thank you very much Georgery.

Comment: Very welcome. Would you mind giving an upvote and mark it as the answer then? (I mean in case it *is* the answer)